# Count instances of first array in second array and return third array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, count

I have two arrays of strings, but for demonstration purposes I will use letters a-e:

{a,b,c,d,e}

{a,a,b,c,c,c,d,e,e}

I want to count instances of each element in the 1st array as elements in the second array, and return a third array (with the length of the first array) of the count.

For example, given the two arrays above, my program should return:

{2,1,3,1,2}

Alternatively, a method for taking the second array:

{a,a,b,c,c,c,d,e,e}

and returning:

{a,b,c,d,e}

{2,1,3,1,2}

would serve my program's purpose as well.

I know in JavaScript I can do this:

```
function foo(arr) {
    var a = [], b = [], prev;

    arr.sort();
    for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        if ( arr[i] !== prev ) {
            a.push(arr[i]);
            b.push(1);
        } else {
            b[b.length-1]++;
        }
        prev = arr[i];
    }

    return [a, b];
}
```

How would I do this in Visual Basic?

Comment: In C#, using LINQ: `b.Where(c => a.Contains(c)).GroupBy(c => c).Select(g => g.Count())`, where `a` is the first listing and `b` the second.

Comment: Alternatively: `var result = (from item in a select b.Count(text => text == item)).ToArray();` (But that's C#, no idea how that looks in VB)

Comment: @MatthewWatson - What zero counts? But yes, filtering out would do that.

Comment: @Oded: I mean that if you run it with `{a,X,c,d,e}` /`{a,a,b,c,c,c,d,e,e}` it will output `2,3,1,2` when it should output `2,0,3,1,2`

Comment: @Oded: Well, the OP did say the length of the resultant array should be the same as that of `a`; but reading the alternative part of his specification, it looks like there would never be any missing strings, since he's deriving the first array from the second. So your suggestion would always work, if that was the case.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this (straightforward):

```
Dim strings() As String = {"a","b","c","d","e"}
Dim stringsToCheck() As String = {"a","a","b","c","c","c","d","e","e"}
Dim results(strings.length) as Integer

For Each strToCheck as String in stringsToCheck
   For Each str As String in strings
      If strToCheck.Equals(str) Then
         results(strings.IndexOf(str)) += 1
         Exit For
      End If
   Next
Next
```